# NSInteger multiplication: Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsinteger, multiplication

I try to multiply two NSIntegers, but Xcode gives me an error:

```
NSInteger singlePage = ((NSInteger)floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f)));
NSInteger page = singlePage * visiblePages;
```

And the error itself:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSInteger' (aka 'int') and 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *'))
```

NSInteger visiblePages is already defined and is being passed to a method.
I think that the compiler thinks that the * is a pointer sign and not a multiplication symbol. Is there any other method to multiply two NSIntegers?

Comment: try to change NSInteger into float. and page should be int.

Comment: Tried to cast into (int) and it worked, but the mistake was described in Sviatoslav Yakymiv's answer. It caused error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined `visiblePages` incorrectly.
Replace

```
NSInteger *visiblePages;
```

with

```
NSInteger visiblePages;
```